# Is there any way in .net/C# to copy a table structure from one database to another one?

Tags: c#, sql, copy, structure

I have two databases - one is full and another is used as cache for a few tables. Is there any way in C# to clone the table (including structure and data) to destination database? (The source database is too big to copy all of them to destination one).

Comment: Are the two databases on the same db server?

Comment: Ideally you would do this in SQL server (no need to copy the entire database), not in C# - any reason you need to do it in C#?

Comment: You could use SQL Server DTS tool to copy table data & structure

Comment: I think the best way to transfer all data and structure is to use the [Transfer SQL Server Objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx) task in SSIS. Although presumably once the structure is set up once, you would only need to copy the data? Could you use replication? Or could you just copy over new data?

Comment: I don't have enough permission on the source database. sp-help command  works and I can also see all data; but no permission to get "Create Table" script.

Answer (score 4):

open a SqlConnection and execute a query similar to this:

```
select * into 'db2'.dbo.tablename from 'db1'.dbo.tablename
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet; but will this one create the table if not exist on destination DB?

Comment: Yes, it will create the table if it doesn't exist.  Bare in mind, it will have no indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are some administrative tools from SQL Server to do this kind of tasks easily. If you want to do that inside C#, I don't know other way different than querying the catalog and then comparing, rebuilding the whole stuff in the other database.

Some years ago, I started an open source MSBuild Task to do that. The source code is in [this sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbinfo/). Probably I'll migrate this code to github, but as you can see, there are not so much evolution for a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Bulk Copy here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4s223c6.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: This only deals with inserting the data, not copying the table structure.